# Cordova android app working on offline mode

Tags: android, cordova, networkstatsmanager

I am working on cordova android app. I have stored all JSON data on local storage which comes on my apps dashboard page from server database. I have also checked "navigator.connection.type" in if else loop to run code accordingly to call offline function or online function in deviceready. when my device changes from online to offline or verse a versa, if my phone is in offline function then it shows offline data still if i have network connection. and when i run project code from cli using command cordova run android -device then only it refreshes shows alerts. Now please help to get network information updated once i goes online or offline.

Comment: you should use online and offline events to track the phone network connection

Comment: i have used " document.addEventListener("online", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);" this  but it does not call any of the function shows blank screen on device. but when i use "document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);" this it calls "onDeviceReady" function and it shows dashboard.html page

Comment: document.addEventListener("online", onDeviceReady, false);  define seperate function for online event. Dont use onDeviceReady

Comment: yes.. got it.. Thank you very much

Comment: welcome. Happy coding